# Installing VC++ 2010 doesn't fix dll loading problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mdd

I have a C++ `.exe` compiled with `/MDd` (since I can't use CLR with /MTd). At first I was getting `couldn't find x.dll` that is installed when installing the VC++ runtime. After I installed the VC++ 2010 runtime, I still get the error. I've verified that the `.dll` it's looking for (`msvcpsomethingd.dll`) is located in the correct folder (`[SystemDrive]\Windows\system32`). Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

[How to deploy debug CRT .dlls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[How to deploy CRT .dlls in general to the application local folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293565.aspx)

The short answer is you have to explicitly install the CRT debug runtime for VS 2010 with a custom setup project on the target machines OR ensure the CRT .dlls for the platform are in the same folder as the application.

You will have to explicitly install the CRT if you are using multiple versions of the debug CRT (i.e., x86 and x64).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve these issues is to use the [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool. Profile the program and it will tell what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with release mode and run on different PC. It seems like one/more of your DLLs are compiled using Debug build or dependencies.

It could be your referenced library as well..

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that correct Redestributable of VC++ 2010 is installed:

- 32-bit OR 64-bit, depending on your application, **not** as per target OS.
- Appropriate RTM or Service Pack version.